# MySQL: Using JOIN statement in a subqery

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

Joins can be formulated in an explicit syntax ([INNER|LEFT|OUTER|..] JOIN... ON...) or specifying the conditions in the WHERE statement.

How can I refer to a table called in the external FROM statement and JOIN it in the subquery?

In this case I'm referring to the table with the alias p

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.post_title,
    (SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wp_terms.name
                    SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM
            p
                JOIN
            wp_term_relationships ON (p.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
                LEFT JOIN
            wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                LEFT JOIN
            wp_terms ON (wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id)
                AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy IN ('post_tag' , 'category'))
FROM
    `post_senza_revisioni` p
WHERE
    p.post_type = 'post'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p.post_parent = 0
GROUP BY id , post_title
```

Comment: You can use p columns in the subquery conditions, i.e. a correlated subquery. But you can't select from p.

Comment: Giving invalid code can't tell us what you want, it doesn't mean anything. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. PS p is an alias for post_senza_revisioni, you could use that. PS A table alias is not used to denote the value of the table, it is used to denote an arbitrary row from that table--hence we dot it to get the value under a particular column for that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you want a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT p.id, p.post_title,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wp_terms.nameSEPARATOR ',')
        FROM wp_term_relationships tr
             wp_term_taxonomy tt
             ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id LEFT JOIN
              wp_terms t
              ON t.term_id = tt.term_id AND
                 tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag' , 'category'))
        WHERE p.id = r.object_id
       )
FROM `post_senza_revisioni` p
WHERE p.post_type = 'post' AND
      p.post_status = 'publish' AND
      p.post_parent = 0;
```

I doubt the `GROUP BY` is needed in the outer query, so I removed it.  If you do have duplicate `id` values in the `p` table, then you can add it back in -- although that suggests that `id` is a really bad name for the column.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the data you, I think you should be able to use the sub query in the FROM clause, join on the ID and then just select * or your desired columns from the sub query.

```
SELECT 
    p.id,
    p.post_title,
    sub.*
FROM
    `post_senza_revisioni` p

JOIN    (SELECT 
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT wp_terms.name
                    SEPARATOR ',')
        FROM
            p
                JOIN
            wp_term_relationships ON (p.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
                LEFT JOIN
            wp_term_taxonomy ON (wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
                LEFT JOIN
            wp_terms ON (wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id)
                AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy IN ('post_tag' , 'category')
        ) sub
ON p.id = sub.id
WHERE
    p.post_type = 'post'
        AND p.post_status = 'publish'
        AND p.post_parent = 0
GROUP BY id , post_title
```

Comment: **Why** do you expect `FROM P` to work in a sub-query?

Comment: Copy and paste error, maybe try bringing in the  post_senza_revisioni.